# pandas.read_feather got an unexpected argument nthreads

Tags: python, pandas, feather

I tried saving a dataframe to feather format but while loading back I got the error

```
os.makedirs('tmp', exist_ok=True)
df_hist.to_feather('tmp/historical-raw')
```

Here's the loading back into the dataset

```
df_hist= pd.read_feather('tmp/historical-raw')
```

which gives the following error

```
read_feather() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nthreads'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried updating your pandas and pyarrow installations? There are some workarounds offered [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23053).

Comment: Which version of pandas you are running with?

Comment: @pygo I am running the latest version. Tried updating but requirement already satisfied

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try replacing below line

```
df_hist= pd.read_feather('tmp/historical-raw')
```

with

```
import feather
df_hist=feather.read_dataframe('tmp/historical-raw')
```

above change worked for me

Answer (score 2):

read_feather function is as follows:

```
feather = _try_import()
path = _stringify_path(path)

if feather.__version__ < LooseVersion('0.4.0'):
    return feather.read_dataframe(path)

return feather.read_dataframe(path, nthreads=nthreads)
```

The read_feather function calls the feather.read_dataframe inturn. You can import feather and call feather.read_dataframe('path') directly.

```
import feather
feather.read_dataframe(path)
```