# can't open ftr file in python

Tags: python, pandas, feather

I want to open a feather file in python, however below 2 approaches both not working. Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

**1. py.read_feather**

```
import pandas as pd
houses_rawdata = pd.read_feather('test_file.ftr')
```

outputs:

```
TypeError: read_feather() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nthreads'
```

**2. feather.read_dataframe**    refer to this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23053

```
import feather
houses_rawdata = feather.read_dataframe('test_file.ftr')
```

outputs:

```
ArrowInvalid: Not a feather file
# I'm sure the feather file is correct
```

Comment: Which version of Pandas are you using? And is there a chance you could make the (small?) test feather file available for other people to try and test themselves?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54004206/14168623) answer your question?